# Apache loads any file that begins with the same string as used in url. How to prevent this?

Tags: apache, macos, apache2, httpd.conf

If I point to:

*mywebsite.com/search*

and there is a file called *search.php* or *search.html* or *search.inc.php* or *search.whatthehell.php* in website's directory, Apache will point to that file instead of 404'ing.

What is even more annoying is that if I point to:

*mywebsite.com/search/string?also=whatever*

Apache will still display any file with filename that begins with "search.".

Also, all RewriteRules with patterns containing filenames existing in directory are ignored/useless.

I'm using Apache 2 on Mac, unmodified httpd.conf. How do I prevent it from redirecting my urls so freely?

Comment: Do you have mod_speling enabled?

Comment: Thanks, but it's the same thing with mod_speling disabled.

Comment: OK, do you have cache modules enabled? If so, does disabling caching as well as mod_speling still cause this problem?

Comment: When I disable cache_module I get "[notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down" and Apache won't even restart... Disabling disk and mem cache doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to disable MultiViews option using Options directive. This is a feature of the apache content negotiation module, so if you don't use mod_negotiation you can just unload it.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/content-negotiation.html

Example of how to disable MultiViews for the /var/www directory:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews